# No TypeScript error when using an undefined global variable in a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined

I am new to typescript. I thought it was supposed to catch stuff like this, but maybe I just don't understand it well enough. The problem comes up when I try do something like this:

```
interface A {
  prop: string
}

let a: A

function f() {
  console.log(a.prop) // Runtime error
}

f()
```

There is no error telling me that `a` might be undefined in the function, or that `a` should be defined immediately because otherwise it's undefined and that doesn't fit the type `A`, or at least that it should be typed like `A | undefined`.

When you type it like `let a: A | undefined`, you immediately get an error in the function that `a` might be undefined. This is what I would expect to see, if `let a: A` is actually also allowing it to be undefined.

Am I missing something? Is there a setting in tsconfig that I should turn on? I am using strict already.

Answer (score 2):

`let a: A;` is a declaration that says to TypeScript "*I'll initialise this later, before I use it, it'll always be an `A` one way or another*". And TypeScript will actually complain if you attempt to use it subsequently without assigning an `A` to it first - but this kind of control flow analysis does not extend to function calls, where it becomes a very hard problem.